# how to display euro symbol in css after and before pseudoelements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I can't figure out how to let CSS display the Euro symbol (€) in `:before` and `:after` pseudoelements.

```
.my-span:after {
    content: '&euro;';
}
```

Tried with the symbol `€`, `u20AC` and `%u20AC`. Nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use escapes like this `content: '\20AC';`, which can be useful in some cases, such as for white space characters, but for the euro symbol, just go with Advocation's answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the character “€” as such works provided that the declared character encoding of the CSS file (or, if the style sheet appears inside an HTML file, of the HTML file) coincides with the actual encoding.

Since servers normally do not specify character encoding for CSS files, it should suffice to save the file as UTF-8 encoded *with BOM*. The BOM lets browsers auto-recognize the encoding.

If this is not feasible, use the method mentioned by @Alohci: `'\20AC'`. This is a [CSS escape](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters) that works independently of character encodings, but it’s not particularly readable.

Comment: Despite `'\20AC'` being less readable, I'd prefer it over coupling encodings between my HTML and CSS. Using an escape is the more reliable option and you're bound to run into them at some point so knowing what they are by that time isn't a bad thing either :)

Answer (score 8):

You should just be able to use the symbol - http://jsfiddle.net/8Wz9B/

```
.my-span:after {
    content: '€';
}
```

Comment: Thank you but as I said in question, I already tried it and it didn't work. Jukka's answer solved my problem.

Comment: Heads up: if you try this in SCSS (SASS) and try to compile it, the compiler will throw an error because of an unexpected character. I tested with Prepros v4.

Comment: Tied it using SASS 3.4.18 and it didnt't throw an error. It did output random characters, though...